# How to call the javascript variable in JSON header for JMETER

Tags: javascript, json, jmeter

I just have the "JSR223 postprocessor" in Jmeter with below script

```
var context_data = {"referralId":${referral_id}};
console.log(context_data);
const secret = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(JSON.stringify(context_data))
console.log(secret);
const encoded_referral_id = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(secret);
console.log(encoded_referral_id);
```

The above script I need to get "encoded_referral_id" value and need to pass another input request header section.

Can someone help me how can I get the "encoded_referral_id" and pass it to another subsequence API header.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could create a variable within the [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and read the value of the variable in subsequent components including header.

**Steps 1** : Creating the variable encoded_referral_id

```
vars.put("ENCODED_REFERRAL_ID", encoded_referral_id )
```

**Step 2** : Reading value of the variable

```
${ENCODED_REFERRAL_ID}
```

JMeter Variables [API documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) could be useful to get an idea of available methods for manipulating the variables.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting, using JavaScript is some form of a performance anti-pattern so consider migrating to Groovy language
2. [Never inline JMeter Functions or Variables into JSR223 scripts](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)
3. All your code does is Base64 encoding so you can use [__base64Encode() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) which will be even more easy and fast

- Example implementation using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy):

  ```
   ${__groovy(('{"referralId":' + vars.get('referral_id') + '}').bytes.encodeBase64().toString(),)}
  ```
- Example implementation using __base64Encode() function:

  ```
   ${__base64Encode({"referralId":${referral_id}},)}
  ```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)